# How to set ListView footer to IsVisible=false

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

This is the XAML code of the footer:

```
  <ListView.FooterTemplate IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}">
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout Padding="8">
        <Label Text ="Loading ..." 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}"                                                   
                Color="Blue" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>        
  </ListView.FooterTemplate>
```

The `ActivityIndicator` is working as intended (it stops when `IsLoading` is set to `false`). But I want to make the whole footer disappear once `IsLoading` is set to `false`, and I am not able to make this happen.

Comment: Try passing a nullable IsLoading, once it is loaded, set it to null

Comment: @AkashKava It throws a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when executing `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` (just when `IsLoading` is set to `null`).

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `BindingContext` for the `Footer` and change the `IsVisible` to the `StackLayout`:

```xml
<ListView Footer="{Binding IsLoading}">     
    <ListView.FooterTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding .}" Padding="8">
                <Label Text="Loading ..." HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding .}" Color="Blue" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I had tried to do that. But if I bind IsVisible to whichever element is the child of DataTemplate, it just leaves an empty space at the bottom of the list. That is: the space that was formerly used by the footer still remains, but its elements are not visible anymore